# Hessian: C++ server

Tags: java, c++, serialization, hessian

I am going to write a client-server application using Hessian protocol for binary serialization.
Do you know if there is a way to do it with C++ server and Java client?
I have found only vice versa examples (Java server and C++ client).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using a common protocoll, of course!

Comment: As bash.d pointed out, it makes no difference what language you use for the client and server, as long as you are using the same protocol. Why would it?

Comment: I see in hessiancpp code for client only support. I've seen example for server/client in C# implementation of hessian, but it's too old and I need C++.

Comment: @Andrey Pervunin: can you please post the source where you've found the examples? Thanks.